# Yii - How to Prevent User Accessing Login Page After Login

Tags: php, yii

everyone.
I want to prevent user accessing login page after they have logged in.
What is the best way to do that?
Here's the code of config/main/php

```
return array(
'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
'name'=>'My Web',
'defaultController' => 'site/login')
```

And SiteContoller.php

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    $model=new LoginForm;

    // if it is ajax validation request
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    // collect user input data
    if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        if($model->validate() && $model->login()){
            $isAdmin = Yii::app()->user->getLevel() <=1; // or how you define admin in your case.
            if ($isAdmin)
                $this->redirect(array('user/view', 'id'=>Yii::app()->user->id));
            else
            //$id = Yii::app()->user->id;
                $this->redirect(array('site/index'));
        }
    }
    // display the login form
    $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

In `'defaultController'=>'site/login'` I also want user not accessing login page after they close brower and reopen it. Is that possible? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way, its simple .

```
public function actionLogin()
{

   if(!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
   {
       $this->redirect(array('index')); 
   }

   // rest of the codebelow.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the access rules and add the url's of different types of user access. 
For ex:

```
class YourController extends Controller {

public function filters() {
    return array(
        'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
    );
}

/**
 * Specifies the access control rules.
 * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
 * @return array access control rules
 */
public function accessRules() {
    return array(
        array('allow', // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions' => array('index', 'view'),
            'users' => array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow Only logged in user's to delete and update
            'actions' => array('delete', 'update'),
            'users' => array('*'),
        ),
        array('deny', // deny all users
            'users' => array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

It's the best, easy and appropriate method to use in Yii..

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with the use of [Sessions](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html). What you'll want to do is start sessions running at the top of your code. You may need to include this in other sections of code if you ever refer to a user being logged in or not.

```
$sid = $session_id();
if(isset($sid)){
    //session exists
} else {
    start_session();
}
```

After this, you will want to add a session entry to keep track of if you have a logged in user or not. I recommend doing this when you have confirmed that the user is logged in as such:

```
// collect user input data
    if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        if($model->validate() && $model->login()){
            // store that the user is logged in
            $this->session->set_userdata(array('loggedIn' => true));
            $isAdmin = Yii::app()->user->getLevel() <=1; // or how you define admin in your case.
            if ($isAdmin)
                $this->redirect(array('user/view', 'id'=>Yii::app()->user->id));
            else
            //$id = Yii::app()->user->id;
                $this->redirect(array('site/index'));
        }
    }
```

Finally, you can do a check in your code BEFORE you get to the form processing stuff to see if anyone is logged in using the session variables. If they are, you can send them on to the site/index or user/view, otherwise continue on as you were.

```
if(isset($this->session->userdata('loggedIn')){
    //user is logged in, redirect away from this page
}
// else the user is not logged in and continue as normal
```

Ideally, you can use the above three lines plus the session_start() code to check if a user is logged in on any page, which is generally a good way to implement private/public pages, as well as letting people close the browser/page and then returning without being logged out.